# Drawing pie charts with D3, using JSon

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm drawing a pie chart with D3. Data is fetched from the DB. Sample JSon is given below. My chart should have SLA compliance as the legend and the pie chart should be drawn with SLA compliance's values(here it is 100), for every month. Legend is coming fine. Here, the 'SLA Compliance' is a label that changes with different charts when other radio buttons/drop down are clicked. On printing the values in the console, I found that when Var pie is called, the value in it is coming as undefined. Chart is not getting displayed. Can someone help me out.

Sample JSON:

```
[
 {month:"Nov-11", 'SLA Compliance':100},{month:"Dec-11", 'SLA Compliance':100}, 
 {month:"Jan-12", 'SLA Compliance':100}, {month:"Feb-12", 'SLA Compliance':100}, 
 {month:"Mar-12", 'SLA Compliance':100}, {month:"Apr-12", 'SLA Compliance':100
]
```

Code:

```
function drawPieChart3(xData,data,svg,index,selectedIndex){
    var width = 400, 
        height = 100,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .outerRadius(radius - 10)
        .innerRadius(0);

    var pie=d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null)
        .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

    var temp= d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "month"; })
    color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "month"; })); 

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.month=d.month
        d.pieValue = temp.map(function(name) {  
            return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });


    var g=svg.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "arc");

        g.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .style("fill", function(d) {return color(d.data.month); 

        g.append("text")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.month; });


    //legend portion 
    alert("11. in legend portion")
    var mylegend = svg.selectAll(".mylegend")
        .data(temp)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "legend")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + (legentCount+i+1) * 20 + ")"; });

   mylegend.append("rect")
        .attr("x", width+40)
        .attr("width", 18)
        .attr("height", 18)
        .style("fill", color);

   mylegend.append("text")
        .attr("x", width+60)
        .attr("y", 9)
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", "start")
        .text(function(d) { return d; });


  }
```

Comment: you're missing a closing brace in the last item. is that a typo?

Comment: for(var i=0; i< xData.length; i++){
   var temp = '{"month":"'+xData[i]+'"';
        for(var j=0;j< pie.length;j++ ){
            var tempJson = pie[j];
  for(var k=0;k<tempJson.length;k++ ){
      
     if(k==i){
          temp+=','+tempJson[k];
  }
 }
     }
  temp+='}';
        pieJson.push(temp);

Comment: for(var i=0; i< xData.length; i++){
  var temp = '{"month":"'+xData[i]+'"';
      for(var j=0;j< pie.length;j++ ){
      var tempJson = pie[j];
      for(var k=0;k<tempJson.length;k++ ){
      
       if(k==i){
        //alert("inside innermost for: "+tempJson[k]);

       temp+=','+tempJson[k];
      }
       }
     }
     temp+='}';
    //alert("In draw chartpie part temp size 5/6"+temp.length); 
    pieJson.push(temp);

Comment: for(var i=0; i< xData.length; i++){
     var temp = '{"month":"'+xData[i]+'"';
 for(var j=0;j< pie.length;j++ ){
     var tempJson = pie[j];
  for(var k=0;k<tempJson.length;k++ ){    if(k==i){
           temp+=','+tempJson[k];
   }
  }
  }
  temp+='}';
        pieJson.push(temp);

Comment: this is the code which generates the array.

Comment: Its a single code.. Got pasted thrice.

Comment: In order to draw the value of "SLA Compliance", you need to actually refer to it. I can't see it anywhere in the code.